# PBXCp Error ShareKit.bundle is not built

Tags: ios, xcode, build, sharekit

I'm working on a rather old iOS Xcode project using ShareKit.
I have updated ShareKit to the newest available version following the [installation guideline](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit).

After working through all of the update issues and errors I've hung up with this PBXCp Error now.

```
CpResource /Users/[...]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[...]-bzxpcpjwjqtbdmaryzugwajcrijj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[...]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ShareKit.bundle /Users/[...]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[...]-bzxpcpjwjqtbdmaryzugwajcrijj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[...]/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/[...].app/ShareKit.bundle
cd /Users/[...]/front-mobile/src/iOS
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/[...]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[...]-bzxpcpjwjqtbdmaryzugwajcrijj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[...]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ShareKit.bundle /Users/[...]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[...]-bzxpcpjwjqtbdmaryzugwajcrijj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[...]/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/[...].app

error: /Users/[...]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[...]-bzxpcpjwjqtbdmaryzugwajcrijj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[...]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ShareKit.bundle: No such file or directory
```

What I perceive is that at the clean project state the ShareKit.bundle file and all other files beneath ShareKit.xcodeproj/Products/ are red (meaning unbuilt?).

After building only the files ShareKit.bundle, libBuffer.a and Static Library Tests.xctest remain red. To me as a non iOS and Xcode professional it seems that the ShareKit.bundle file is just not being built and thus is not available for the Copy Bundle Resources section of my project's Build Phase.

See a [screenshot](http://img42.com/FUed5+) after a build attempt.

How can i find out, why the ShareKit.bundle is not built?

How can i possibly fix the missing build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this  issue while adding resources to a static library.I think this can be a solution to your issue too. I think the bundle and .lib were not being built.
I clicked on "edit schemes"(edit the scheme) and under the “Build” tab click the plus at the bottom and add the library target and library resources target.

For more info please refer this
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Answer (score 1):

Just add "Resources Bundle (ShareKit)" to Build Phases/Target Dependencies of your project and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using static library and then decided to use cocoapods for this framework then maybe u could forget ShareKit bundle into Copy Bundle Resources under the Build Phases tab of XCode 6.

Check Out there and u can see the  ShareKit bundle which is written red. Delete this bundle and then u can move on! :)